# Need help solving a problem with pandas series

Tags: pandas

[Hello](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwSKz.png)

I have two columns, yr_built and yr_renovated. yr_renovated has alot of zeros. I want to replace those zeros with the average. I have done this already. I have figured that homes built from 1900 to 1950 were on average renovated in 1992. So what I want to do is that for every row in yr_built that has value between 1900 to 1950, 1992 will be added to the corresponding row under yr_renovated.

I have tried this code below but does not work.

```
kc['yr_renovated'] = kc[['yr_renovated','yr_built']].apply(lambda x: 1992 if kc[kc.yr_built] >= 1900 & kc[kc.yr_built] <= 1950 & kc[kc.yr_renovated] == 0 else 'False')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please paste your data into a format that others can use. For example, you can use `df.to_dict()` or `df.to_csv()` to provide an easy output for us to use on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [(df['yr_built'] >= 1900) & (df['yr_built'] <= 1950) & (df['yr_rennovated'] == 0)]
values = [1992]

df['yr_rennovated'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```